# ReactJS: Incorrect rendering of a list of components

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, constructor, components

I have a component ("ComponentA") that is rendered multiple times in a map() inside the render() of another component ("ComponentB").

Furthermore, I have an "ADD" button in ComponentB, which when clicked, pre-pends (via 'unshift() method) an object in its ComponentB's "state.objects" array (used for mapping instances of ComponentA).  Each prepended object has a property 'prop1' that I set ComponentA's input text value with.

The problem is that I wasn't getting expected values in the state of each instance of ComponentA: in all instances the  element always has the value '1' (I expect ... 3, 2, 1).

What's more, I see that ComponentA's constructor is called only once each mapping loop, and specifically just before the render() call for the last instance.

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
    class ComponentB extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props) // added upon first reply
        this.handleObjectAdd = this.handleObject.bind(this);
        this.state.objects = [];
      }

      handleObjectAdd() {
        this.state.objects.unshift({prop1: this.state.objects.length + 1});
      }

      render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.handleObjectAdd}>ADD</button>
              { this.state.objects.map((object, index) =>
                  <ComponentA key={index} details={object}/>
                )
              }
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    }

    class ComponentA extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props) // added upon first reply
        console.log('ComponentA constructor called');
        this.state = { details: props.details };
      }
      render() {
        console.log('ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is ' + this.state.details.prop1);
        return (
          <input type="text" value={this.state.details.prop1}></input>
        )
      }
    }
```

So with the code above, clicking on the ADD button once logs the following:

```
    ComponentA constructor called
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
```

Clicking on the button a 2nd time logs:

```
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
    ComponentA constructor called'
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
```

Clicking on the button a 3rd time logs:

```
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
    ComponentA constructor called'
    ComponentA render() called, prop1 value is 1
```

... and so on.

In all instances of ComponentA, input text value is "1".

My questions are:

1) How do I code it to get the desired increasing value rendered for ComponentA?

2) Why is the constructor of the mapped component called only once, and at that specific position (just before the last rendered instance)?

NOTE:
The code above is just a simplified version of my actual code, showing only the essential parts to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You [should never mutate the state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) by doing something like `this.state.objects.unshift()` - use `this.setState()` instead. When you modify an array or object inside `this.state` directly, React has no idea that some value inside it was changed. This answers both your question. Thus, instead of modifying `this.state.objects` directly:

```
this.state.objects.unshift({prop1: this.state.objects.length + 1});
```

you should prepend a new item to the array in an immutable way:

```
const newItem = { prop1: this.state.objects.length + 1 };
this.setState({
  objects: [newItem].concat(this.state.objects)
});
```

Apart from that, you forgot to call `super(props)` inside the constuctors of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`. Also, there is no need to copy passed props into components state inside `ComponentA` - just simply use props. You can see working codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ov6m8k2qy).

Comment: Thanks @Volodymyr, I do have super(props) in my actual code, but added them above.  I also used your code pattern for prepending an element to my array.  But I do need the <input> editable by the user and this does not work: <input value={this.props.details.prop1} ...>, but this does: <input value={this.state.details.prop1} ...> .  I'm still getting the wrong output.

Comment: Actually in my actual code instead of <input> I have an input component that is a controlled component, and passing it the props for value makes it non-editable, so Im passing it the state value.  I'm still getting the same wrong output.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to share my actual code.  But good news is that I was able figure out the issues.  They were basically caused by using state instead of props for for the value attributes.  So the solution was of the nature: <input value={this.props...} onChange={}, instead of <input value={this.state...} as in my code above.  I'm a newbie, and grateful for your corrections, like the immutable changing of array values you showed above, so that React can detect the state change.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issues came from using this code:

```
    <input value={this.props....} onChange={...} // first version
```

instead of

```
    <input value={this.state....} onChange={....} // second version
```

I previously thought the the second version was correct and that the first version prevented the input from being editable.  But it seems that the presence on onChange made the first version work (correctly displaying initial and edited values and allowing editing)